# Apache Spark, createDataFrame example in Java using List<?> as first argument

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone give an example of java implementation of 
`public DataFrame createDataFrame(java.util.List<?> data,java.lang.Class<?> beanClass)`
function, as mentioned in Spark JavaDoc?

I have a list of JSON strings I am passing as the first argument and hence I am passing `String.class` as the second argument, but it gives an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

not sure why, hence looking for an example.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your using of **Bean Class**.

From [JavaBeans Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans):

> JavaBeans are classes that encapsulate many objects into a single
>   object (the bean). They are serializable, have a zero-argument
>   constructor, and allow access to properties using getter and setter
>   methods. The name "Bean" was given to encompass this standard, which
>   aims to create reusable software components for Java.

To be more clear, let me give you an example using Java Bean in Spark:

Suppose we use this Bean class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Bean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String k;
    private String something;

    public String getK() {return k;}
    public String getSomething() {return something;}

    public void setK(String k) {this.k = k;}
    public void setSomething(String something) {this.something = something;}
}
```

And we have created `b0` and `b1` that are instances of Bean by:

```
Bean b0 = new Bean();
b0.setK("k0");
b0.setSomething("sth0");
Bean b1 = new Bean();
b1.setK("k1");
b1.setSomething("sth1");
```

Also we have added beans(`b0`,`b1` here) into a `List<Bean>` called `data`:

```
List<Bean> data = new ArrayList<Bean>();
data.add(b0);
data.add(b1);
```

Now we can create a `DataFrame` using `List<Bean>` and `Bean` class:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, Bean.class);
```

If we do `df.show()`, here is the output:

```
+---+---------+
|  k|something|
+---+---------+
| k0|     sth0|
| k1|     sth1|
+---+---------+
```

**THE BETTER WAY TO CREATE DATAFRAME FROM JSON STRING**

In Spark, you could directly create `DataFrame` from a List of JSON Strings:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(jsc.parallelize(data));
```

where `jsc` is an instance of `JavaSparkContext`.

Answer (score -1):

I invite you to look at the spark source code where there are plenty of examples, especially in the unit tests, you can find all references of `createDataFrame` in java [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=createDataFrame+language%3Ajava&type=Code).